# Spring DefaultTuple not serializable

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-jdbc, spring-xd

I'm using spring-xd 1.3.0 release to process a tuple message.

After using some taps to enrich a message, I've made my own aggregator to re-assemblate the resulting messages.

Now I would like to use a postgreSql message store, to have persistence in case of crashing node.

So I roughly copy-pasted the original [xml configuration file](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/blob/master/modules/processor/aggregator/config/aggregator.xml) of the original spring-xd aggregator.

Then I built and deployed the following stream:

```
stream create aggregate --definition "queue:scoring > scoring-aggregator --store=jdbc --username=${spring.datasource.username} --password=${spring.datasource.password} --driverClassName=${spring.datasource.driverClassName} --url=${spring.datasource.url} --initializeDatabase=false > queue:endAggr"
```

but when I send my usual tuple message to this stream, that got correctly processed by an in-memory store, I get:

```
xd_container_2 | Caused by: org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.xd.tuple.DefaultTuple
xd_container_2 |        at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:68) ~[spring-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
xd_container_2 |        at org.springframework.integration.jdbc.JdbcMessageStore.addMessage(JdbcMessageStore.java:345) ~[spring-integration-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
xd_container_2 |        at org.springframework.integration.jdbc.JdbcMessageStore.addMessageToGroup(JdbcMessageStore.java:386) ~[spring-integration-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
xd_container_2 |        at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.store(AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.java:604) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
xd_container_2 |        at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.java:400) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
xd_container_2 |        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

and now... well  I'm stuck and dont have any idea how to proceed.

Any hint appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tuple is not `Serializable` - I am not sure why - but XD uses Kryo for serialization internally (by default); you could add [kryo transformers](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html#_encodingpayloadtransformer) before/after the aggregator as a work around.

**EDIT**

Another option is to convert the `Tuple` to json, using `--inputType=application/json` on the `aggregator`.

See [type conversion](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#type-conversion).

The aggregator output would be a collection of JSON strings, getting them back to Tuple would depend on what you are doing downstream of the aggregator.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'm rather new to spring and I can't see how I could "add" a kryo transformer; should I add a stream that just convert the message to another type, or is there some beans I can add in the aggregator xml config file to serialize/deserialize the input/ouytput channel?

Comment: You could use custom modules up/down stream of the aggregator, or customize the aggregator itself. Also see my edit for another alternative.

Comment: Ok, that's what I had in mind. I'm a little disappointed because I had a hard time turning all my data processing to Tuples - with the belief that I would gain in performance by using the inner data structure mode of XD- , but not being serializable nor castable to string make them not so convenient to use, don't you think?

Comment: I personally agree; I suggest you open an ['Improvement' JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD) to see what the team thinks. It won't be so trivia as just adding `Serializable` because the tuple internally has transient references to type conversion mechanisms which would have to be reestablished during deserialization.